# JavaScript decode API response and make html elements

Tags: javascript, html, json

How can I use JavaScript to decode my API response
api.site.com:

```
{
  "background_img": "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/workplace.jpg",
  "OB": [
    {
      "shape": "rect",
      "coord": "34,44,270,350",
      "title": "Computer",
    },
    {
      "shape": "poly",
      "coord": "290,172,333,250",
      "title": "Phone"
    }
  ]
}
```

and use data to make html elements

```
<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm">
  <area shape="poly" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="phone.htm">
</map>
```

It could be more that 2  depends on API response (means use for loop)

I have tried the code below ***except the loop part just separates data from the response***

```
    <script>
let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = response.background_img;
        document.getElementById("a1").shape = response.OB[0].shape;
        document.getElementById("a1").coords = response.OB[0].coord;
        document.getElementById("a1").alt = response.OB[0].title;
     
    }
};
xml.open("GET", "https://api.site.com/example", true);
xml.send();
        </script>
```

but when i try this code to buid multi elements i got this error:
`forEach is not a function`

```
    let xml2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var i=0;
        response2.forEach(element => {
                var area = document.getElementsByTagName('map')[0],
                newArea = document.createElement('area');   //create an area
                newArea.id = `a${i}`;                      //add an id
                newArea.shape =response.OB[i].shape;
                newArea.coords =response.OB[i].cord;
                newArea.alt =response.OB[i].title;
                area.appendChild(newArea);                 //append to the map
                i++;
        });
    }
};
xml2.open("GET", "https://api.site.com", true);
xml2.send();
```

Comment: *"the loop part"*: I don't see a loop part. Also: where do you take the "OB" property into account? What is "tags"? That is not present in your sample response?

Comment: @trincot hi yes as i said except i didn't use for loop i change the response thats why my code is not ok take a look at this code again i edited

Comment: _“but i don't know how to make html element”_ - well then go _research_ it …? Type “javascript dynamically create html elements” or something similar into Google, and see what you get … You people need to stop showing up here with “I don’t know”, and then expect us to provide beginner tutorials for you. That is not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

It would look something like this:

```js
let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = response.background_img;
        document.getElementById("a1").shape = response.OB[0].shape;
        document.getElementById("a1").coords = response.OB[1].coord;
        document.getElementById("a1").alt = response.OB[1].title;
        document.getElementById("a1").href = response.OB[1].productid;
    }
};
xml.open("GET", "https://api.site.com/example", true);
xml.send();
```

Hope this works for you!

If you have multiple items, you can use a for-loop which would look like this:

```js
let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        response.forEach(element => {
            // Do something for every element in response here
        });
    }
};
xml.open("GET", "https://api.site.com/example", true);
xml.send();
```

Comment: thanks the first part of your code is works but the second part i don't know how to generate html elements in js i can do with angular for in html but can not do that here

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not an array as you can clearly see in the data that you have put at the top of your question. This is also what the error message is saying when you try `response.forEach`. The *array* is stored in the `OB` property. So your should loop over *that*.

Note also that `forEach` provides the index to the callback function, so there is no need to manage your own counter variable.

I would also suggest to use the `fetch` API instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, which is a bit easier to use, and its response object has a method for parsing JSON as well:

```
fetch("https://api.site.com").then(resp => resp.json()).then(function (data) {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = data.background_img;
    let area = document.querySelector('map');
    data.OB.forEach(function (element, i) {
        let newArea = document.createElement('area');
        newArea.id = `a${i}`; // Try to avoid the need for an ID attribute here
        newArea.shape = element.shape;
        newArea.coords = element.coord;
        newArea.alt = element.title;
        area.appendChild(newArea);
    });
};
```

I would also suggest to avoid the use of an automatically generated `id` attribute. In most cases (if not all), you can do without it.